# Evaluate $\int \int_{R} (2x-3y)^2(x+y)^2 dx dy$ using substitution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\int \int_{R} (2x-3y)^2(x+y)^2 dx dy$$ when $R$ is the triangle blocked by the positive X-axis, negative Y-axis and $2x-3y=4$, using $u=x+y$, $v=2x-3y$.

How do I find the limits of integration? in the X-Y axis it is $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{4}{3}}^{0}(2x-3y)^2(x+y)^2 dy dx$$

But what are the limit in U-V axis?

Comment: Are you sure those are the limits? It seems to me that it should be the *positive* Y-Axis to have a bounded triangle.

Comment: @AugSB checked again positive X-axis, negative Y-axis, add a mistake in the function, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Solving $u=x+y$ and $v=2x-3y$ for $x$ and $y$ yields:
$$x = \frac{1}{5}\left( 3u+v \right) \quad , \quad y = \frac{1}{5}\left( 2u-v \right)$$

In the $xy$-plane the bounding lines are $y=0$ (the $x$-axis), $x=0$ (the $y$-axis) and $2x-3y=4$. These boundaries become:
$$x = 0 \to 3u+v = 0 \Leftrightarrow \color{blue}{v = -3u}$$
$$y = 0 \to 2u-v = 0 \Leftrightarrow \color{blue}{v = 2u}$$
$$2x-3y = 4 \to \color{blue}{v = 4}$$
The region bounded in the $uv$-plane by these lines is a simple triangle (a sketch is useful), e.g. let $v : 0 \to 4$ and then $u : -\tfrac{v}{3} \to \tfrac{v}{2}$. Don't forget the Jacobian.